# Blender mesh deformed in unreal

Tags: blender, mesh, unreal-engine4

I have a model with a mesh and 4 wheels. The base is the father of the 4 wheels. The base has its origin on (0,0,0) the world origin.

First, If the wheels has their origins in their bottom (the z axis is 0), the object doesn´t cross (origin: (0,0,0) ) the floor but the wheels are deformed.
[the origin of wheels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jc1fz.png)
[deformed wheels in world origin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fms5i.png)

However, if the wheels has their origin on the center of each one, the object crosses the floor and the wheels are deformed too.

[deformed wheels cross the floor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Flt2.png)

It might be an error with transformation, but I'm not sure. How can i fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to animate it, just build a skeleton, but if you want to have this mesh being static, just select all and press f.

And i think to keep their transform try to do **Ctrl + p** and click on *Object (keep transform)*

Comment: Thanks you! I was following an example and It hasn't got bones. I am trying to do a toy car so it isn't static but the wheels has a script to move them. I will try to parent them with ctrl+p

Comment: I tried to do Control+P but it doesn´t work, the wheels are still deformed

Comment: I tried to do a bone for each wheel and the base, It moves but instead of going forward, It goes to the right